# Share a wikipage to external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

How can i share a wiki library (some pages) to an external user without to grant access to all other pages/contents on the sitecollection? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No If you are giving a visitor permission level to external user it will have visitor permission on whole of subsite or site collection.

For this workaround you can do is to have a code(CSOM) on your master page which will check the user and the current url so if the user is external and url is other than the page for which he has access redirect him to error or access denied page